# How should I do functional testing without Requirments?

Tags: manual-testing, bug-report, functional

When you are testing without requirments you can rely on your own logic and common expectation from your user experience.

So let's say I'm testing a button `Process and Send` (input stuff for data is working fine).

[image]

I press the button, and see the correct results of data processing on the screen, but there is no sending action is happening or it's happening but there is no way for user to guess where it is send to.

So the question: what kind of bug reports should be created?

1. Sending functionality is not working
2. Missing fields for specifying destination for sending processed data
3. Incorrect naming of `Process and Send` button

Comment: +1 because I function test without requirements all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there are no requirements, I would say go with your first option.  You are relying on normal expectations based on the button text.  If the bug is rejected, you can ask why.

Better yet though, find someone who should know (PM/BA/Customer or maybe even the dev) and find out what it's supposed to do.  The more information you have, the better bug report you can create and the faster it can be resolved.

Comment: I guess it would be the best to merge 1 and 2 into one bug report: report name "Sending functionality is not working" and description will include expected actions like selecting destination dialog or extra Browse button to select destination directory or file.

Comment: yes, number one may very well be a symptom of number 2

Comment: Right, the key point is "You are relying on normal expectations based on the button text" - so interface is my functional requirements and it says "Send"